# Fill tensor by repeating last element (tensorflow)

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have a tensor of video frames of the following shape `(frames, 128, 128, 3)` where frames varies between 25 and 36. Now I would like the tensor to be of fixed size `(36, 128, 128, 3)` by repeating the last frame `36-frames` times.

I can extract the last frame with a shape of `(128, 128, 3)` the following way:

`shape = tf.shape(video)
last_frame = tf.gather_nd(video, [shape[0]-1])`

I want to repeat it now `36-shape[0]` times and add it at the end of `video`.
How can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by selecting your last element, replicate it n times with tf.tile, and then concatenate your result.

```
last = frames[-1]
last_35 = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(last, 0), [35-tf.shape(frames)[0] ,1,1,1])
frames = tf.concat([frames, last_35], 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [tf.concat()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/concat) to concatenates the list of tensors, [tf.tile()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tile) to creates a new tensor by replicating input multiples times, [tf.reshape()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reshape)

```
tf.concat([video, tf.reshape(tf.tile(last_frame], 36 - shape[0]), [128, 128, 3]), 0)
```

Comment: I am afraid `tf.tile` second argument has to contain 3 numbers so `tf.tile(last_frame, 36-shape[0])` is not working

Comment: @BernhardKratzwald The third parameter is optional, check the doc.